# Which type of locking mode for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operations in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, rowlocking

I know that NOLOCK is default for SELECT operations. So, if I even don't write `with (NOLOCK)` keyword for a select query, the row won't be locked.

I couldn't find what happens if `with (ROWLOCK)` is not specified for UPDATE and DELETE query. Is there a difference between below queries?

```
UPDATE MYTABLE set COLUMNA = 'valueA';
```

and

```
UPDATE MYTABLE WITH (ROWLOCK) set COLUMNA = 'valueA';
```

Comment: Why did you get the impression that `NOLOCK` is the default?

Comment: @MartinSmith This is written in [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172398(v=sql.110).aspx) as `This is the default for SELECT operations.`

Comment: That is not documentation about the tagged product. "Using locking hints in SQL Server Compact 4.0 is similar to that of SQL Server. **However, for SQL Server Compact 4.0, the NOLOCK hint has a very different behavior than it does for SQL Server** In SQL Server Compact 4.0, the NOLOCK hint is the default for SELECT statements, but this still enforces Read Committed behavior."

Answer (score 0):

If there is no hint, then the db engine chooses the LOCK mdoe  as a function of the operation(select/modify), the level of isolation and granularity, and the possibility of escalating the granularity level. Specifying ROWLOCKX does not give 100% of the result of the fact that it will be X on a rows. In general, a very large topic for such a broad issue

Read first about Lock Modes that https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx
If

Comment: There will be lots of things to learn about lock modes for me. Thanks for the link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> So, if I even don't write with (NOLOCK) keyword for a select query, the row won't be locked.

select queries always take a lock and it is called shared lock and duration of the lock depends on your isolation level

> Is there a difference between below queries?
>
> UPDATE MYTABLE set COLUMNA = 'valueA';
> and
> UPDATE MYTABLE WITH (ROWLOCK) set COLUMNA = 'valueA';

Suppose your first statement affects more than 5000 locks,locks will be escalated to table ,but with rowlock ...SQLServer won't lock total table

Comment: 1. Not 5000 rows, but 5000 locks. 2. If escalation is allowed

Answer (score 0):

In statement 1 (without rowlock) the DBMS decides to lock the entire table or the page that updating record is in it. so it means while updating the row all or number of other rows in the table are locked and could not be updated or deleted.

Statement 2 (with (ROWLOCK)) suggests the DBMS to only lock the record that is being updated. But be ware that this is just a HINT and there is no guarantee that the it will be accepted by the DBMS.